# How can I keep circleimageview ahead of a CardView? in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, cardview

**I want to show output in such a way that CircleImageView is ahead of CardView**

[image: Enter Image Description]

**But my output looks like this**

[image]

**This is my Single Row XML which I want to use with RecylerView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">


<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cat_placeholder"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/red"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    app:cardElevation="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circleImageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circleImageView" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap imageview and cardview in a frame layout and use margins to overlap

Comment: I try to do it thank you

Comment: it's not working @YashJoshi

Comment: The `CircleImageView` has a lower elevation than `50dp`, so you need to either set a higher elevation or make them the same, but swap their declarations in your XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:elevation="55dp"` to your imageView

Comment: Not 55dp, just 5dp.

Comment: cardview has 50 dp elevation so it need 50+5 @LalitFauzdar

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping your `CardView` and `CircleImageView` in a `FrameLayout`. Also, set the `android:elevation` property for both views in the way that you want them to appear.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/some_container"
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_height="..."
    ... >

    <CardView
        android:id:"@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="..."
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:elevation="..."
        ...
        ... />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_placeholder"
        android:elevation="..."
        ...
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

Don't forget to check the [FrameLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) for understanding how best to use it. (Also, remember that a `CardView` is itself a `FrameLayout`.)

---

Additionally, I would suggest paying attention to the `minSdkVersion` of your project. The `elevation` property is available in API 21+ . Your app won't crash in lower API devices, but you might not get the look you need. Strongly consider using the FrameLayout for achieving overlap, or try designing custom views or using some library, e.g. for shadows to simulate elevation.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, a correction in my answer: I think the CardView has a separate elevation property (the one you have in your code sample; do check before using). If my response above solves your issue, do mark it as an answer. Thanks.